# Do I need to add implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:2.1.0' when I use Kotlin for Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I have read the artical at https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview

Do I need to add `implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:2.1.0'` when I use Kotlin for Google Play?

I'm learning the [office sample code](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/TrivialDriveKotlin), but I find the sample code doesn't add it, you can see at [here](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/blob/master/TrivialDriveKotlin/app/build.gradle).

Answer (score 5):

I will try and answer your question without really knowing that specific library.
The article states the following (which I assume you have read):

> If you're using Kotlin, the Play Billing Library KTX module contains
>   Kotlin extensions and coroutines support that enable you to write
>   idiomatic Kotlin in your Play Billing solution. To include these
>   extensions in your project, add the following dependencies to your
>   app's build.gradle file

So that means that you will need the "billing-ktx" library/extension if you want to write "idiomatic Kotlin" using the extensions and coroutines, contained in "billing-ktx". 
But you can of course, still write kotlin code without this extension lib.

If I was in your place (without much knowledge of the library), I would start out with the basic "com.android.billingclient:billing:2.1.0". If the need to use the extension presents itself later on, I would simply add it then.